# How to Vertically align text next to an image in contentful

Tags: contentful

How to vertically align text next to image in contentful.

Please check the following link https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsxDx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this:

1. You define some CSS to center the image. this works when you have, let's say, articles where the images are always on the same position and should look the same. (`display: block; margin: 0 auto;` or something should do the trick)
2. If there are several images which will have different looks it's recommended to devide the big markdown blog into several content types and entries – creating a set of building blocks so to say. This way you could have a `page` content type which references text blocks and images which are all configurable. This approach is called ["Topic and assemblies"](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/topics-and-assemblies/)
3. The third approach I can think of (**not recommended though!**) is to add some HTML to your markdown to style the images like you want it. This has the big downside that you loss cross-platform compatibility.

In either case, Contentful only handles the content and you have to make the centering happening in your site/application yourself.

Hope that helps. :)